# Find records which have multiple occurrences in another table array (postgres)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select

I have a table which has records in array. Also there is another table which have single string records. I want to get records which have multiple occurrences in another table. Following are tables;

**Vehicle**

```
veh_id |             vehicle_types              
-------+---------------------------------------
    1  | {"byd_tang","volt","viper","laferrari"} 
    2  | {"volt","viper"}                        
    3  | {"byd_tang","sonata","jaguarxf"}        
    4  | {"swift","teslax","mirai"}              
    5  | {"volt","viper"}                        
    6  | {"viper","ferrariff","bmwi8","viper"}   
    7  | {"ferrariff","viper","viper","volt"}
```

**vehicle_names**

```
    id |  vehicle_name
  -----+-----------------------
    1  |  byd_tang
    2  |  volt
    3  | viper
    4  | laferrari
    5  | sonata
    6  |  jaguarxf
    7  |  swift
    8  |  teslax
    9  | mirai
    10 | ferrariff
    11 | bmwi8
```

I have a query which can give output what I expect but its not optimal and may be its expensive query.

This is the query:

```
select veh_name 
from vehicle_names dsb
where (select count(*) from vehicle dsd
       where dsb.veh_name = ANY (dsd.veh_types)) > 1
```

The output should be:

```
 byd_tang
 volt
 viper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be an aggregation query:

```
SELECT
   vn.id,
   vn.veh_name
FROM vehicle_names vn
INNER JOIN vehicle v
   ON vn. veh_name = ANY (v.veh_types)
GROUP BY
  vn.id,
  vn.veh_name
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This only counts a vehicle name which appears in two or more *records* in the other table.  It would not pick up, for example, a single vehicle record with the same name appearing two or more times.